Recovering music from Generalmusic WX 2 song files
I don't know whether this is the right place to ask, but I'll give it a shot:
I used to own a Generalmusic WX 2 keyboard (built in the 1990s, I guess) with built-in sequencer on which I created some songs as a teenager/young adult. Now I stumbled upon some backed up song files on my PC and I wonder whether it is possible to recover (parts of) the music without having the actual instrument.
The manufacturer doesn't exist anymore (so cannot be asked) and I've already searched on Google but didn't find anything. What I'm looking for would be along the terms of

a file format specification
already existing software that can read/convert/etc. those files (e.g. conversion to MIDI)
other ideas? (excluding getting the specific instrument - that's obvious)

Any help is appreciated (including referring to other sources).
